# restrict blocks in multilanguages site

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I want create a multi language website, I have some problems,
according my search about menu link in multilanguage  drupal website ( I did this job in some year ago but forget it(because some personal life change I abandon drupal form 1 year) ) it is better to create  seperate  menu type and put them in menu block (with menu block moudle ).but I have some problesm,
first How can I restrict block  shows in only specify language , I want did it in cofiguration of block in **pages** section limit it by something like 
***en/****  but in front page of my two languages not work correctly,
please tell me how can I restrict blocks in languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use The Block languages module, part of the [Internationalization (i18n) package](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) allows you to configure for which languages each block is visible. The settings for visibility per language are provided under Visibility Settings via the Languages tab when configuring a block.

Comment: Thanks ,I found it before you say  :) **Block languages** . how ever thank you (y)

Comment: Ok that's fine. By the way which Drupal version do you use ?

Comment: I am using  Drupal 7 .

Comment: I usually use Drupal 7 too. Have a good day :)